# Stretchy Header in UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout in ios 14?

Tags: ios13, swift5, ios14, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout, uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource

How can I override layoutAttributesForElements in UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout ?

```
    func createCompositionalLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { sectionIndex, layoutEnvironment in

        return layout
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Are you just trying to create one stretchy header at the top of a `UICollectionView`?

If so, you can add a `UIView`, which is your "stretchy header", to your `UICollectionView`, then you can do something like:

```swift
import SnapKit


// ...

header.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.top.left.right.equalTo(self.view)
    make.bottom.equalToSuperview()
}
```

[Btw, I assumed we are using SnapKit!](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit)